# Passing an attribute name to a function in Python

Tags: python, attributes

How do I pass the name of an object's attribute to a function? For example, I tried:

```
def foo(object, attribute):
    output = str(object.attribute)
    print(output)

class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

apple = Fruit("red")
foo(apple, color)
```

but the above doesn't work because Python thinks that, in `foo(apple, color)`, the `color` refers to an unitialized variable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. If you try to call `foo(apple, color)`, you get a `NameError` because `color` isn't defined in the scope from which you're calling `foo`; and
2. If you try to call `foo(apple, 'color')` you get an `AttributeError` because `Fruit.attribute` doesn't exist - you are **not**, at that point, actually using the `attribute` argument to `foo`.

I think what you want to do is access an attribute from a string of the attribute's name, for which you can use `getattr`:

```
>>> def foo(obj, attr):
    output = str(getattr(obj, attr))
    print(output)


>>> foo(apple, 'color')
red
```

Note that you shouldn't use `object` as a variable name, as it shadows the built-in type.

---

As a demonstration of point #2:

```
>>> class Test:
    pass

>>> def demo(obj, attr):
    print(attr)
    print(obj.attr)


>>> t = Test()
>>> t.attr = "foo"
>>> t.bar = "baz"
>>> demo(t, "bar")
bar # the value of the argument 'attr'
foo # the value of the 'Test' instance's 'attr' attribute
```

Note that neither value is `"baz"`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `getattr`:

```
>>> print getattr.__doc__
getattr(object, name[, default]) -> value

Get a named attribute from an object; getattr(x, 'y') is equivalent to x.y.
When a default argument is given, it is returned when the attribute doesn't
exist; without it, an exception is raised in that case.
```

In your case define foo like this and pass the attribute as a string:

```
def foo(object, attribute):
    print(getattr(object, attribute))
.
.
.
foo(apple, 'color')
```